# Node.js subdomain not working?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, subdomain

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am trying to do requests from a virtual subdomain using `npm subdomain`. I followed the directions https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/subdomain

```
var subdomain = require('subdomain');
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var http     = require('http');
var server   = http.createServer(app);

app.use(subdomain({ base : 'localhost', removeWWW : true }));

app.get('/subdomain/blog/', function(request, response) {
  response.end('BLOG.LOCALHOST: "/"');
});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.end('LOCALHOST: "/"');
});
```

And in my computers hosts file I added

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   blog.localhost
```

When I route to `http://blog.localhost:3000/` I get this returned `LOCALHOST: "/"` instead of `BLOG.LOCALHOST: "/"`

I can't figure out why, I removed my express router, I tried removing any routing logic and stuff but I still keep getting that. Obviously I am doing something wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I see they pass in the *require subdomain* into app.use, followed by the params. If I reformat their example to look more like your code:

> app.use(require('subdomain')({base: 'yourdomain.com'}));

Note they don't pass in anything to the require subdomain. Instead they pass in the JS object which includes the base AFTER they close the require.

Right now your code looks like this.

> app.use(subdomain({ base : 'localhost', removeWWW : true }));

So instead try this:

> app.use(subdomain()({ base : 'localhost', removeWWW : true }));

OR this:

> app.use(require('subdomain')({ base : 'localhost', removeWWW : true }));

And let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: IDK what just happened but doing this `app.use(subdomain({ base : 'localhost', removeWWW : true }));` just worked, I think its the exact same thing though. It's weird that it works now, I am trying to create another server in the app and on the second server port it worked.

Comment: I know what it is, I am using browser sync and browser sync is on port 3000 and has a proxy for my main server on 9200, it has something to do with that. Believe me though I did try using 9200 directly earlier but it wasnt working then, maybe something was off, but it seems to be good now.